# how to create swipe through photos functionality in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, photo, swipe

I want to be able to swipe through a series of images in my iPhone app like in the Photos app.  I want to have the pictures reside on the phone in the app itself.

I know the facebook three20 api does this but it reads the images from a url.

Does anyone know how I can implement this functionality?

Comment: Isn't the three20 api open source? Take a look at how they do it, then instead of fetching a picture from a URL, just create a UIImage using [UIImage imagedNamed:@"YourImage.png"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the 'swipe through' functionality, you'll have you use a `UIScrollView` with horizontal scrolling. The `bounds` of the `UIScrollView` should be set to the total available space, probably the whole screen (`CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)`) and the `contentSize` should be the total width of the screens with images, so `number of images * 320`. The height of this `contentSize` should be set to the height of the `UIScrollView` itself, so only horizontal scrolling is possible.

For snapping to each image (so that would be every 320px) you can set the `pagingEnabled` property to `YES` (Thanks @Ben in the comments!)

Comment: To snap to each picture use the property on UIScrollView pagingEnabled = YES